# How do you create a control during runtime on iOS

Tags: controls, ios4

Is there a way to create a control during runtime? I tried something like

```
UIButton* tempButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 160, 40, 40)];
[self.view insertSubview:tempButton atIndex:0];
[tempButton release];
```

it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIButton* tempButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 160, 40, 40)];
[self.view insertSubview:tempButton atIndex:0];
[tempButton release];
```

Comment: Is buttonWithType a ready made method that gives you the UIBUtton? And I think you can not release it.